Send a mouseclick to an X window in the background, without bringing it to the foreground
How do I send a mouseclick action / hold mousebutton to a window in the background, without bringing the window to the front?
I want to be able to interact with other windows while holding down a mousebutton in a specific application.

try moving the window off screen and then send a click to it

This would work, but it does not work if I want to send a "mousedown" (so a button hold without release). As soon as I click anything in another window, the button gets released in the target window.

this may be a starting point ... https://superuser.com/questions/505780/linux-second-monitor-as-terminal ... also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012352/linux-dual-mice-multiple-mice-with-multiple-mouse-pointers#16509176

You might be hitting one of my bugbears... the separation of "click to focus" and "focus raises" (or "click to raise").  Older window managers (eg fvwm1.2 what I used 20+ years ago) could do this but modern window managers seem to combine "click to focus and raise".  So when you use xdotool to click on a window the it raises.  It may be possible to work around this with "focus on mouse" so where the mouse is pointing has the focus but this isn't what I want for a UI.

34 years a very useful X11 tool was released that can help you suppress
given events going to an application. Though xmon is sadly no longer
included by many distributions, you can download the
sources from 2017 and recompile it. I
just did this, using xmkmf from package imake, to convert the
Imakefile into a Makefile, then running make. I had to add gcc option
-fcommon to CDEBUGFLAGS in the Imakefile first, due to changes in gcc.
You will also need several development packages to have the X11 .h include
files.
Testing showed that the tool expects to be able to connect to the X11
server over tcp, rather than Unix Domain sockets, as is usually the case
these days, for security. You can restart your X11 server with option -listen tcp to
allow connections (but you also need to do more to disable remote access, so
only do this in a closed network).
Instead, for testing I just ran a server-within-a-server:
Xnest :1 -ac -listen tcp

You now run xmon telling it to connect to this new server:
./xmonui | ./xmond -ascii -port 2 -server localhost:1 &

You will see a window of options from xmonui, but xmond will not try to
connect until you launch a client. For example, from another terminal:
DISPLAY=:2 xev

If it fails you may need to change localhost:1 to use your actual hostname.
Add -verbose 1 -debug 255 if you need to debug.
xmond will die if it cannot connect to the server, but xmonui will not
notice, so you will need to kill it.
If you click a mouse button in the xev window, you should see the usual
ButtonPress and ButtonRelease events from the xev output, and from
xmond you should see lines like
..............EVENT: 04 ButtonPress
..............EVENT: 05 ButtonRelease

Click in the gui to select "names", so the full event is not printed.
Now, in the bottom right panel, click on 5 ButtonRelease to select it;
you should see an asterisk: 5 * ButtonRelease. Ensure the blocking itme
above the list is set to on.
When you now click in the xev window, you will no longer see
ButtonRelease events from xev.


This solution is as impressive as it is concerning. I will accept it as a correct (even though I have not tried it), but present my actual solution (which is also a workaround) as a separate answer.

I was not able to solve this directly.
The answer from @meuh may work, but it is probably not wise to use it in a productive system, for both security and usability reasons.
I was however able to find several workarounds which may be useful to others with a similar problem:

Xephyr - nesting your X session allows you to send events to the nested session in a more controlled manner, as you can more avoid accidentally sending unwanted input (such as a mouse button release) by not interacting with the nested session window.
Wayland + xdotool (my actual solution) - Wayland (as opposed to X11) does not send a button release if one uses xdotool to send a mousedown and interacts with a different window after that.

